# How to install PyGTK MacOs catalina 2020

Tags: python, macos, pygtk

I am trying to install a software called p4vasp:
https://github.com/orest-d/p4vasp/blob/master/README.MacOS.
I am getting this error message:
You need to get version 2.0 (or later) of PyGTK for this to work. You can get source code from http://www.pygtk.org
So I go there and follow the steps, but when I try to run the python script hello.py it fails:
File "hello.py", line 1, in 
import gi
ImportError: No module named gi.
I think this could the problem.
pygobject3 3.36.1 is already installed and gtk+3 3.24.22 as well.
I have tried all the solutions, none worked so far.. Could someone help me please?
Thank you in advance.
Best wishes to all

Comment: Do you have git?

Comment: Hi @Haversine thank you for your answer. What do you mean? I shared the git of the program if someone would like try to reproduce the problem. Regarding pygtk there is the official site as well from where you should be able to get it.  Cheers